# Action Filter Never Being Hit In ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jsonp, action-filter, actionfilterattribute

I have no idea why my action is not being hit.  This controller is under an "Area" called api.

```
$.ajax({
            url: defaults.url + (defaults.url.indexOf('?') > 0 ? '&' : '?') + 'r=' + Math.random(),
            type: defaults.method,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: defaults.data,

            success: function (data) {


    public class EventController : Controller
        {
            [JsonpFilter(Order = 1)]
            public JsonResult Register()
            {

                return new JsonResult
                {
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                    Data = new ApiRegistrationResponse()
                };
            }
        }

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class JsonpFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");

            string callback = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["callback"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(callback))
            {
                var result = filterContext.Result as JsonResult;
                if (result == null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("JsonpFilterAttribute must be applied only " +
                        "on controllers and actions that return a JsonResult object.");
                }

                filterContext.Result = new JsonpResult
                {
                    ContentEncoding = result.ContentEncoding,
                    ContentType = result.ContentType,
                    Data = result.Data,
                    Callback = callback
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in the filter? Is the controller code executing? Can you breakpoint in the controller? Just trying to get all the pieces

Comment: Yes the controller method is hit, but I even overrid all the actionfilter methods with breakpoints and couldnt hit any of them.

Comment: @MikeFlynn: Did you register the action filter?

Comment: No, I've never had to register an action filter before, or am I off on that?

Comment: I registered it as a global filter and it worked, but every action call is now using it.

Comment: I just added the same OnActionExecuted to the controller and it worked.  Why in the world is the filter not working????

Comment: Just a suggestion, change AttributeTarget to Method, instead of all

Comment: Yes, you have to register action filters (Unless they're in the form of an attribute, in which case you can apply that attribute to an action method and it will run)

Comment: As you can see above I am using it on an action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trial and error I had to exclude the following ninject file `NinjectMVC3.cs` under the `App_Start` folder and it started working.

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MvcApplication2.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(MvcApplication2.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "Stop")]

namespace MvcApplication2.App_Start
{
    using System.Reflection;
    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;
    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Mvc;

    public static class NinjectMVC3 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(HttpApplicationInitializationModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
        }        
    }
}
```